# Algebra of Time Reversal and Particle Hole Symmetry in 10-fold Classification of Topological Insulator/superconductor

Tags: electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, topological-phase, charge-conjugation

In the ten fold classification of TI/TSC, when time reversal symmetry $\mathcal{T}$ and particle hole symmetry $\mathcal{P}$ are both present, i.e., in the symmetry classes BDI, DIII, CII, CI, for all the models in the literature that I can see, I found that $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ commute. Concretely, 
$$[\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{P}]=0$$
where $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{P}$ are matrices that act on the single body Hamiltonians. Is there a physical reason of why they should commute?